# Read and write .bmp file with MIPS

Tags: mips

I try to open a .bmp file(230454 bytes) and write to another .bmp file. It didnt work, can anyone tell me why?

Files are in the same dir with Mar4_5.jar

When I debug, the program read smt to buffer but I cant print it out, even to console.

```
.data
fin:    .asciiz "1.bmp"
fout:   .asciiz "1_out.bmp"
buffer: .space 250000
    .text

main:

li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
la   $a0, fin      # board file name
li   $a1, 0        # Open for reading
li   $a2, 0
syscall            # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
move $s6, $v0      # save the file descriptor 

#read from file
li   $v0, 14       # system call for read from file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor 
la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer to which to read
li   $a2, 230454     # hardcoded buffer length
syscall            # read from file

# Close the file 
li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor to close
syscall            # close file


li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
la   $a0, fout      # board file name
li   $a1, 0        # Open for reading
li   $a2, 0
syscall            # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
move $s6, $v0      # save the file descriptor 


li   $v0, 15       # system call for read from file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor 
la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer to which to read
li   $a2, 230454     # hardcoded buffer length
syscall            # read from file

# Close the file 
li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor to close
syscall            # close file

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Could you add information on how you've tried to isolate the issue?

Comment: You're opening the output file with `$a1 = 0` (read-only).